# What could cause a sudden stop in Box2D?

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm using Box2d for a game, and I have a bug that's driving me nuts. I've simplified the situation down to a square player sliding back and forth frictionlessly on top of a floor composed of a series of square tiles, driven by the left and right keys (which apply a horizontal force). Works great, sliding back and forth across the whole floor.

Except... Every once in a while, the player will suddenly stick at the edge of one of the tiles as if it is hitting a (nonexistent) wall. Further pushes in the same direction it was traveling will fail, but as soon as I push backwards once in the opposite direction, I can push forwards past the sticking point again. The sticking point seems to be random, except for being on the edge of a tile. Happens while going left or right.

For debugging purposes, I keep the Positions/velocity values for the previous two update ticks and print them out when this stop occurs. As an example, here you see the player moving right, decelerating slightly; pos2 should be about 8.7, but it stops dead instead.

```
tick0:  pos= 8.4636 vel= 7.1875
tick1:  pos= 8.5816 vel= 7.0833
tick2:  pos= 8.5816 vel= 0.0000
```

So, as the player is 0.8 and the tiles 1.0 wide, the player is stopping just as it is about to cross onto the next tile (8.5816 + 0.8/2 = 8.9816). In fact, I get a collision message (which I ignore except noting that it happened). It only seems to happen at x.5816 (or -x.4184) while moving right, and x.4167 (or -x.5833) while moving left

I said that it's like hitting a wall, but in fact, when it hits a wall, the numbers look more like:

```
 tick0:  pos0= 12.4131 vel2= 8.4375
 tick1:  pos1= 12.5555 vel1= 8.5417
 tick2:  pos2= 12.5850 vel0= 0.0000
```

so it moves further right on the last tick, which puts it in contact with the wall.

Anyone seen anything like this? Any suggestions on how I could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue in Box2d... [from the FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/wiki/FAQ):

> **Tile Based Environment**
>
> Using many boxes for your terrain may not work well because box-like
>   characters can get snagged on internal corners. A future update to
>   Box2D should allow for smooth motion over edge chains. In general you
>   should avoid using a rectangular character because collision
>   tolerances will still lead to undesirable snagging.
>
> For more information see this post:
>   http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3048

And from Eric Catto, creator of Box2d (Emphasis added):

> I'm working a solution for edge chains, but there is no solution for
>   adjacent polygons. **You are really better off using one or more circles
>   for character vs environment**. Most professional games using modern
>   physics engines use smooth shapes, like capsules, for characters.
>   Using box shapes for characters really only works well in systems that
>   use pixel based collision with integral math (i.e. older console
>   games).

So basically, your body should be a smooth shape, and not a polygon so that it doesn't snag between tiles.

Comment: Thank you. I searched around and didn't find this, but apparently it was in a place that was TOO obvious.  FYI, I tried a circular shape, but it also hits the internal corners but instead of stopping, it bounces up a little. I'll change over to a single floor instead of multiple tiles.    Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to change the tiles to smooth the body.
I had the exactly same problem.

the short answer is:
`use b2EdgeShape , not b2PolygonShape`

try this:
before I used a polygon shape, and I had those unexpected collisions that you have said

```
b2PolygonShape* pBasic_1X1_Box = new b2PolygonShape();
pBasic_1X1_Box->SetAsBox(1.0f/2.f, 1.0f/2.f); 
m_mapPolygonShape["1X1_Box"] = pBasic_1X1_Box;       
....
pBody->CreateFixture(m_mapPolygonShape["1X1_Box"],0.f);
```

After I used an edge shape then I solved those problems

```cpp
b2EdgeShape* pBasic_1X1_Box_Up = new b2EdgeShape();    
b2EdgeShape* pBasic_1X1_Box_Down = new b2EdgeShape();  

b2EdgeShape* pBasic_1X1_Box_Left = new b2EdgeShape();  
b2EdgeShape* pBasic_1X1_Box_Right = new b2EdgeShape(); 
b2Vec2 v0(-0.5f, 0.5f);                                
b2Vec2 v1( 0.5f, 0.5f);                                
b2Vec2 v2( 0.5f,-0.5f);                                
b2Vec2 v3(-0.5f,-0.5f);                                
                                                         
pBasic_1X1_Box_Up->SetOneSided(v2,v1,v0,v3);           
pBasic_1X1_Box_Down->SetOneSided(v0,v3,v2,v1);         
pBasic_1X1_Box_Left->SetOneSided(v1,v0,v3,v2);         
pBasic_1X1_Box_Right->SetOneSided(v3,v2,v1,v0);        
m_mapEdgeshape["1X1_Box_Up"]    = pBasic_1X1_Box_Up;   
m_mapEdgeshape["1X1_Box_Down"]  = pBasic_1X1_Box_Down; 
m_mapEdgeshape["1X1_Box_Left"]  = pBasic_1X1_Box_Left; 
m_mapEdgeshape["1X1_Box_Right"] = pBasic_1X1_Box_Right;
...
// :x: using edge shape for tile structure                 
pBody->CreateFixture(m_mapEdgeshape["1X1_Box_Up"],0.f);    
pBody->CreateFixture(m_mapEdgeshape["1X1_Box_Down"],0.f);  
pBody->CreateFixture(m_mapEdgeshape["1X1_Box_Left"],0.f);  
pBody->CreateFixture(m_mapEdgeshape["1X1_Box_Right"],0.f);
```

because of mackworth's question itself, I could solve this problem.

Thanks mackworth